# why useradd havent created the standard files?

Tags: centos, useradd

See I have created some user in my CentOS with `useradd` command. And I didn't get any kind of automatic standard dir creation and its not been versatile actually while I am creating that user. see the log please.

```
root@localhost raja]# useradd positiveman
[root@localhost raja]# passwd positiveman
Changing password for user positiveman.
New password:
BAD PASSWORD: it does not contain enough DIFFERENT characters
BAD PASSWORD: is too simple
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
[root@localhost raja]# ls /home/august
[root@localhost raja]# ls /home/august/
[root@localhost raja]# cd /home/
[root@localhost home]# ls
august  positiveman  raja
[root@localhost home]# cd august/
[root@localhost august]# ls
[root@localhost august]# cd ..
[root@localhost home]# cd positiveman/
[root@localhost positiveman]# ls
[root@localhost positiveman]#
```

what might be the reason ?

Comment: if you expect things like this to be done for you by default, use `adduser` instead of `useradd`, if it's available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give some options to `useradd` to create the directory. You can find those in the `man` page:

```
-m, --create-home
       Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files
       and directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be
       defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.

       By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not
       enabled, no home directories are created.
```

Answer (score 1):

`useradd` has largely been replaced by the newer `adduser`, as explained in `man adduser`:

```
   useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
   administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.
```

So, instead of using `useradd`, use `adduser` that will create everything for you automatically:

```
$ sudo adduser foo
Adding user `foo' ...
Adding new group `foo' (1007) ...
Adding new user `foo' (1007) with group `foo' ...
Creating home directory `/home/foo' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for foo
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```